# Unable to convert m4a to mp3

Tags: linux, macos, audio, conversion

My audio container is M4A, but codec is AAC. When I try to convert it into MP3 I got an error:

```
afconvert ~/Desktop/src.m4a -f MPG3 -d .mp3 ~/Desktop/dst.mp3
Error: ExtAudioFileSetProperty ('cfmt') failed ('fmt?')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use ffmpeg?

```
ffmpeg -i file.m4a -aq 2 file.mp3
```

-aq 2 corresponds to -V2 in lame. ffmpeg preserves tags but not cover art.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no ffmpeg installed on OSX so I have to figure out what is wrong with afconvert. Can't install macports or make from sources on that machine.

Comment: @Pablo You don't have to. On the [FFmpeg download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) there's a static build that you can just execute. If you do a `-c:v copy` it might copy the cover art over as well.